# Cosine of the sum of two angles from the half angle formulas

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, math-history

My goal is not necessarily to give the simplest derivation possible. I've been trying to rescue the [half angle formulas](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/06/another-proof-for-two-well-known.html) from oblivion and give them the status they deserve by showing its many applications.

Various proofs of the formulas of compound angles are given [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Compound_Angle_Formulas).

The cosine of the sum of two angles is given by the formula

$$\cos{(\alpha+\beta)}=\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}-\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\tag{1}$$

**Proof**. We take advantage of the *cyclic* nature of the half angle formulas whose proof can be found [here](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/06/another-proof-for-two-well-known.html). The proof of the half angle formulas given in the link makes use of the [Pythagorean trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity) and the [double angle formula for sine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yRAh9gqUw0&t=5s) whose proofs (I hope you clicked on the links) are *independent* of the formulas of compound angles.

Suppose $\triangle{ABC}$ is a triangle with sides $|BA|=a$, $|AC|=b$ and $|AB|=c$. Let $\angle{BAC}=2\alpha$, $\angle{CBA}=2\beta$ and $\angle{ACB}=2\gamma$. Let's start with the right-hand side of formula $(1)$. Substituting from the half angle formulas we have

$$\begin{aligned} \cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}-\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta} &= \sqrt{\frac{s(s-a)}{bc}\cdot{\frac{s(s-b)}{ac}}}-\sqrt{\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{bc}\cdot{\frac{(s-a)(s-c)}{ac}}}\\&=\frac{s}{c}\cdot{\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)}{ab}}}-\frac{s-c}{c}\cdot{\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)}{ab}}}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)}{ab}}\cdot{\left(\frac{s}{c}-\frac{s-c}{c}\right)}\\&=\sin{\gamma}\\&=\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-(\alpha+\beta)\right)}\\&=\cos{(\alpha+\beta)}\end{aligned}$$

$\square$

The other formulas of compound angles can be obtained similarly.

**Questions**: a) Is this derivation correct? Any criticism is welcome. b) Where can I find the historical background of the formulas of compound angles?

Comment: It seems correct to me!

Comment: My understanding is that originally, pre-Calculus, when the domain of the sine and cosine functions are angles, that the derivation of the angle sum formulas was geometric.  You can google "geometric derivation of angle sum formula" to find pre-Calculus *proofs*/discussions.

Comment: It is also my understanding, which may be mistaken, that when Calculus (AKA Real Analysis) was evolving, and Mathematicians decided that Real Analysis definitions of the sine and cosine functions were needed, that care was taken to ensure that these definitions yielded results that were consistent with the analagous results of the Analytical Geometry Trig functions.  In effect, this allowed Real Analysis to *demonstrate* that the desired Real Analysis sine and cosine functions did in fact *exist*.  Again, I am probably on extremely thin ice here.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Now, I would not be surprised if the sum-to-product and difference-to-product identities can be derived similarly.